# Moxa PCI Express board and red-hat 8.7

Tags: linux, module, kernel, redhat, pci

My question is quite specific but maybe someone has idea, and maybe it will be useful for another person.

I use a [Moxa CP-118E PCI Express board](https://www.moxa.com/en/products/industrial-edge-connectivity/multiport-serial-boards/pcie-upci-pci-serial-cards/cp-118e-a-i-138e-a-i-series#resources) providing 8 serial port. I use the provided driver [(Linux Kernel 4.x.x Driver for Multiport Serial PCI Express and Universal PCI Boards v4.2](https://cdn-cms.azureedge.net/getmedia/c93cf256-4b6d-442d-b18c-297902e370a1/moxa-msb-pci-express-universal-pci-boards-linux-kernel-4.x.x-driver-v4.2.tgz)). We connect to various devices using RS485.

It works perfectly with Almalinux 8.5.
It works almost with Almalinux 8.7.... It fully works using RS232. But we have stranges behaviours when using RS485 on port 1 and port 2 of the pci express board. It works on port 3 (and might works on the 5 other ports).

On port 1 and 2, we read every bytes normally but when we send bytes, a few of them looks modified. For exemple, we sent 6C 6F 6C 6F and we received 2C 2F 2C 2F like if some nibbles are modified. This is not 100% every time and if we send several time the pattern, we can get a few 6C or 6F received.
A material cable issue looks excluded has we can reproduce the same problem on 2 differents 8.7 computers (using different cable) while it works when switching to 8.5.

Red Hat/Almalinux 8.5 uses kernel 4.18.0-348 while 8.7 uses kernel 4.18.0-425, so there is only [very little change between both](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/fr-fr/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/8.7_release_notes/new-features#enhancement_kernel). I am not usually that much at low level, but I am wondering, if there can be a conflict in memory that can modify what we send.

Any clues is welcome.

Edit: I will try to provide more details.

**Compilation:**

Compilation of the driver was done like this:

```
//create the /dev/ttyMUEX char files. Majors numbers used are the default ones (30 and 35).
$ ./msmknod 

//Compile the .ko files (mxser.ko and mx and install them
$ make RHEL8P1
```

No error messages appeared. In build.log, only warning about code style are found. This create the ko files (in /lib/modules/4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64/kernel/drivers/char/ and /lib/modules/4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64/misc.

**Usage:**

I can then either reboot or modprobe the modules. Then I see

```
$ lsmod | grep mx
mxser        77824    0
mxupcie      86016    0
```

To switch to RS485, I use :

```
$ muestty -i RS422 /dev/ttyMUE1
```

It responds ok.

To monitor the exchanged message, we have installed minicom.
$ minicom -D /dev/ttyMUE1

We set it to work in `7/E/1 Data/Parity/Stop, 19200 rate`.
Then we type in `hexa 6C 6F 6C 6F`.
The linked device receive `2C 2F 2C 2F`.

Comment: Voting to close as 'needs details ...' . Your question is too open-ended for StackOverflow. Read [mcve] and include the minimal amount of code that demonstrates the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Right, it lacks detail, I agree. I will try to provide more information (it mights take few time, i dont have full access everytime). Moreover, if i find clues, i will post here, in the eventuallity to help.

Comment: I am quite oblige to agree on the close. For information, we have switched to almalinux 9.2, there is an updated driver for kernel 5.X and we don't reproduce the problem on 9.2.